# Not able to load partial view with huge records

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I am able to get the record successfully from database to the view.

When the record is less view gets loaded properly but
when I try to get all record count (29000 approx)

View :

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            User Role Management
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
        <div class="panel-body">
            @Html.Partial("pv_UserRoleCompany", Model)
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel-body -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.panel -->
</div>
```

Partial View:

```
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
<thead>
    <tr>
      Th goes here...
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.TypeList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
               .......
            </td>

        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Controler:

```
 public ActionResult GetAllUserRoleCompany(String Organisation, String RoleName, String UserName, int UserStatus)
    {
        LMTUsage objLMT = new LMTUsage();
        LMTDAL objLMTDAL = new LMTDAL();

        string usrNameWithDomain = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        //string userID = "261213";  // Environment.UserName;
        string userID = "100728";

        ViewBag.UserRoleId = objLMTDAL.GetRoleID(userID);
        objLMT.TypeList = objLMTDAL.UserRoleCompany_GetAll(Organisation, RoleName, userID, ViewBag.UserRoleId, UserName, UserStatus);

        // return Json(objLMT, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        return PartialView("pv_UserRoleCompany", objLMT);
    }
```

Below is the screenshot,

[image]

Note:
Query from SQL server executing all the 29000 records in 9 seconds but displaying those record on view is what creating a problem as it keeps on loading the page continuously.

Thanks

Comment: A use cannot possibly absorb that many records in one view. Use a **server** side paging mechanism to display just a certain amount of records at one time

Comment: to add on to @StephenMuecke datatables has a feature for this. There are some mvc samples around if you google https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side

Answer (score 0):

I like to suggest server side paging. Please follow this link 
[Server side paging in asp.net mvc](http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2015/11/jquery-datatable-server-side-pagination-sorting.html)

You can also think to reduce overhead of data from SQL Server to web application by introducing database side paging. Here is simple example of database paging.
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2362/overview-of-offset-and-fetch-feature-of-sql-server-2012/